# Android: Which adapter for AutoCompleteTextView with SQlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, autocompletetextview, android-loader

I have an old application which is using **AutoCompleteTextView** filtering data (about 3000 items) from an **SQlite** database through a **SimpleCursorAdapter**.

It's working very well, and it's fast.

However, I just realized that `SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)` has been deprecated.

The documentation says it's recommended to use "*LoaderManager with a CursorLoader*" instead. However it seems that the LoaderManager/CursorLoader are to connect to Content Providers, which I do not need, as this SQlite data is only used by my app and doesn't need to be shared to other applications.

Can you please provide some clarity on this topic?

Which is the suggested adapter to use for AutoCompleteTextViews with SQlite data?

Many Thanks

Comment: I would be interested to know if you came to find the answer to this.

Comment: I decided to keep using the SimpleCursorAdapter. I don't have any problems with it, so I don't think it makes sense for me to use Content Providers.